# Change background color of a select list in oracle apex

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex, apex

I would like to change the background color of a select list in oracle apex, lets say I would like to change the blue color to red color, how can I do that??

[image: Select list default color]

Answer (score 1):

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    option:hover {
      background-color: yellow;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <select onfocus='this.size=10;' onblur='this.size=0;' onchange='this.size=1; this.blur();'>
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="opel">Opel</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="opel">Opel</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="opel">Opel</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="opel">Opel</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>

</body>

</html>
```

Applying that snippet in APEX should be like:

[image]

and

[image]